# Express.js pass key name from a variable value in a route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to dynamically pass key name in a route but it is always giving me `undefined`

This is the code I have tried but cannot seem to get it right. The dynamic name I am trying to pass is arrayname which will changed based on the parameter

```
router.get('/searchterm/table/:table/term/:term/fields/:fields/render/:render/arrayname/:arrayname', function (req, res, next) {

    var pagetorender = req.params.render;
    var arrayname = req.params.arrayname;

    db.query('select * from ' + req.params.table + ' where ' + strfields, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
                res.send(err)
            } else {
                console.log(arrayname)
                console.log(result.rows)
                res.render(pagetorender, { arrayname: result.rows })    
            }   
    })
})
```

For example, if I have to pass

```
res.render(pagetorender, { test123: result.rows })
```

It would be like

```
var arrayname = "test123";
res.render(pagetorender, { arrayname: result.rows })
```

Comment: Found solution. Have to put arrayname in square brackets `[arrayname]`

Answer (score 0):

you can get the params with req.param("param name"); so try something like this

```
router.get('/searchterm/table/:table/term/:term/fields/:fields/render/:render/arrayname/:arrayname', function (req, res, next) {

    var pagetorender = req.param("render");
    var arrayname = req.param("arrayname");

    db.query('select * from ' + req.params.table + ' where ' + strfields, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
                res.send(err)
            } else {
                console.log(arrayname)
                console.log(result.rows)
                res.render(pagetorender, { arrayname: result.rows })    
            }   
    })
})
```

the key change is :

```
var pagetorender = req.param("render");
var arrayname = req.param("arrayname");
```